# Read lines from HUGE text files at groups of 4

Tags: python, text-processing, readline, text-files

I am facing a problem with python since a few days. I am a bioinformatics with no basic programming skills and I am working with huge text files (25gb approx.) that I have to process.

I have to read the txt file line-by-line at groups of 4lines per time, which means that the first 4 lines has to be read and processed and then I have to read the second group of 4 lines, and so on.

Obviously I cannot use the readlines() operator because it will overload my memory, and I have to use each of the 4 lines for some string recognition.

I thought about using a *for* cycle with the *range* operator:

`openfile = open(path, 'r')`

`for elem in range(0, len(openfile), 4):`

```
line1 = readline()
line2 = readline()
line3 = readline()
line4 = readline()
(process lines...)
```

Unfortunately this is not possibile because the file in "reading"  mode cannot be iterated and treated like a list or a dictionary.

Can anybody please help to cycle this properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In Python files opened for reading can easily be iterated over in a line-oriented manner - see the section on `file.next()` here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=file.next#file.next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method for lazily reading large files in Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python). You can use that approach and process four lines at a time. Note that it is not necessary to perform four read operations, then do your processing and then four read operations again repeatedly. You can read chunks of a few hundred or thousand lines from the file and then process four lines at a time. When you're finished with those lines, you can continue with reading the file's contents.

Comment: Most everything you say is true, but making a multi-line chunk oriented version of the algorithm is easier said than done...especially for someone without basic programming skills.

Answer (score 5):

This has low memory overhead.  It counts on the fact that a file is an iterator that reads by line.

```
def grouped(iterator, size):
    yield tuple(next(iterator) for _ in range(size))
```

Use it like this:

```
for line1, line2, line3, line4 in grouped(your_open_file, size=4):
    do_stuff_with_lines()
```

**note:**  This code assumes that the file does not end with a partial group.

Answer (score 3):

You're reading a fastq file, right?  You're most probably reinventing the wheel - you could just use [Biopython](http://www.biopython.org), it has tools for dealing with common biology file formats. For instance see [this tutorial](http://www.biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc222), for doing something with fastq files - it looks basically like this:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
for record in SeqIO.parse("SRR020192.fastq", "fastq"):
    # do something with record, using record.seq, record.id etc
```

More on biopython SeqRecord objects [here](http://www.biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc31).

[Here](http://news.open-bio.org/news/2009/09/biopython-fast-fastq/) is another biopython fastq-processing tutorial, including a variant for doing this faster using a lower-level library, like this:

```
from Bio.SeqIO.QualityIO import FastqGeneralIterator
for title, seq, qual in FastqGeneralIterator(open("untrimmed.fastq")):
    # do things with title,seq,qual values
```

There's also the [HTSeq package](http://www-huber.embl.de/users/anders/HTSeq/doc/overview.html), with more deep-sequencing-specific tools, which I actually use more often.

By the way, if you don't know about [Biostar](http://biostar.stackexchange.com) already, you could take a look - it's a StackExchange-format site specifically for bioinformatics.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an infinite loop, and break out of it when you reach the end of the file.

```
while True:
    line1 = f.readline()
    if not line1:
        break

    line2 = f.readline()
    line3 = f.readline()
    line4 = f.readline()
    # process lines
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing it that I can't take credit for but is quite reasonable:

```
for name, seq, comment, qual in itertools.izip_longest(*[openfile]*4):
    print name
    print seq
    print comment
    print qual
```